# Analyzing USB related registers in ARM

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb, usb, linux-device-driver

I want to analyze USB related registers of my ARM-11 processor in Linux to see how my USB driver has configured the registers.
Can you please tell me how I can analyze the registers? If GDB is needed then what steps are needed to do so ?

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  If you have the source and compile, the USB infrastructure will probably have **debug** options.  Turn this on.  You can create *procfs* or *debugfs* entries for each register.  The main USB registers are mainly standard.  Each SOC may have a few extra registers.  You need to determine the controller used.  Look at `dmesg`.  You can attach *gdb* via the [kgdb](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kgdb/EnableKGDB.html), but it is slow and painful.  You are better to instrument the code.